# node.js export dynamic data to csv file

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I am struggling to write data to a CSV in Node.js.

i tried  this code.

```
       async.auto({
        user: function(cb){
            User.findOne({'memberid': currMemberId}).exec(cb);
        },
        billing : function(cb){
           Payment.find({'memberid' :currMemberId}).exec(cb);  
        },
        trans: function(cb){
           Transaction.find({'id':p.ids}) .exec(cb);
        }
    },function allDone(err, async_data) {
         var data= async_data.trans;
            createCSV = function(data){
                    csv().from(data).to(fs.createWriteStream("c:/temp/sample.csv")); 

           } 

   });
```

but it doesn't seem to work. can someone please help? I want to fetch some data from database and  export this data to csv file.database I fetching data similar to sample data fields plus help me.
Thanks

Comment: You just assign an anonymous function to variable createCSV, but never call the function in the code.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you'd include a minimum working program to demonstrate why this isn't working as you expect. The code you've posted doesn't give enough information on its own.

Comment: what is `csv()`? a dependency? if so, which one and where is it defined. I'm guessing its this http://www.adaltas.com/projects/node-csv/ - but you should mention that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing a full example and knowing what the `csv` dependency is, its tricky to help. However, if it is this one http://www.adaltas.com/projects/node-csv/ - then according to the docs you have the data structured wrong. it should be like this:

```
var data= ["name",'accountno','amount','type',['test','12323','200','sal']];
```

i.e. the headers are in the top level array instead of a nested array.

Just a guess really, but might be worth a go...

Comment: i am using node csv npm module top level i declare  var csv = require('csv'); i want to  response date generate csv file and  exports  to my specific path.